# Optimize Kruskal Wallis Test Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, kruskal-wallis

On spotfire i had created several Kruskal Wallis test. First i had created a pivot table and after i did a data relationship (Kruskal Wallis). Then i reflate my tests with a button (script python).

That is my code :

```
kruskal = Document.Calculations[0]
settings = Document.Calculations[0].CalculationSettings

settings.XColumns.Clear()
settings.YColumns.Clear()

for col in EWSWAFER.Columns:
  if "HB" in col.ToString():
    settings.YColumns.Add(col)
  if col.ToString() == "SPLIT":
    settings.XColumns.Add(col)

kruskal.Execute(CalculationExecutionPromptMode.Never)
```

I would like to know if it possible to optimize my code so that the test takes less time. Because sometimes my datatable has 1500 columns and 500 rows.

Thanks for your help and your ideas.
Regards, Laurent